# How to extract a specific key's value from a nested dictionary in python and return a list of the values

Tags: python, python-3.x

Say I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
SOURCE_IDENTIFIERS = {
    Sources.app1.name: {
        "schema_suffixes": ["something", "something2"],
        "identifier_name": "id1"
    },
    Sources.app2.name: {
        "database_name": "app2",
        "identifier_name": "id2"
    },
    "ALL": {
        "identifier_name": "email"
    }
}
```

I eventually want a list that looks like this:

```
["id1", "id2", "email"]
```

How do I get this info?

Answer (score -1):

Use a list comprehension over the values (which are dictionaries with a common key):

```
[d["identifier_name"] for d in SOURCE_IDENTIFIERS.values()]
```

This works because each value in `SOURCE_IDENTIFIERS` is a dictionary with *at least* the `identifier_name` key.

Note that unless you use Python 3.6 or newer, you can't count on iteration over `SOURCE_IDENTIFIERS.values()` to produce the nested dictionaries in a specific order.

Comment: Also can consider a more foolproof way `[d.get('identifier_name') for d in list(SOURCE_IDENTIFIERS.values())]`, but definitely doesn't look as clean.

Comment: @r.ook: using `list()` there is pointless. It produces the exact same result but with the addition of requiring memory allocation for a list object that is then tossed away again.

Comment: @r.ook: as for using `d.get(...)`, that's an option if the specific key is not present in every nested dictionary, but then you could also argue that `[d["identifier_name"] for d in SOURCE_IDENTIFIERS.values() if "identifier_name" in d]` is the better choice.

Comment: Good point on using the `if` instead... as for the `list()`, for some reason I mistakenly thought `dict.values()` wouldn't iterate.